# What property is being used to simplify this logarithm? $ 4^{log_2 n} = n^2$

Tags: summation, logarithms, computational-complexity

I had this equation for calculating this recursion:

$$ T(n) = 4T(\frac{n}{2}) + n  $$

I'm using a recursion tree to solve this, it's similar to this one:
[image]

But anyway what matters is that from the recursion equation I have the following sum:

$$\sum_{i=0} ^ {log_2 n - 1} 4^i * n.$$

Applying the property:

$$\sum_{i=0} ^ {k} x^i = \frac{x^{k+1} - 1}{x - 1}$$

We have

$$\sum_{i=0} ^ {log_2 n - 1} 4^i  = \frac{4^{log_2 n} - 1}{4 - 1};$$

from there the solution manual states that

$$ \frac{4^{log_2 n} - 1}{4 - 1} = \frac{{n^2} - 1}{3}.$$

How come?
$$ 4^{log_2 n} = n^2 $$

Comment: Do you agree that $2^{\log_2n}=n\;$ and $\;4=2^2?\;$  (Formatting note:  use `\log`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How come $ 4^{\log_2 n} = n^2 $?

Because using the definition of logarithm and properties of exponents,

$4^{\log_2n}=(2^2)^{\log_2n}=2^{2\log_2n}=2^{(\log_2n)2}=(2^{\log_2n})^2=n^2$.